# Angular 14 Error: Transform failed with 1 error: ERROR: Unterminated string token

Tags: css, angular, sass, node-sass

When running ng serve I have this result:

> *./src/main.ts - Error: Module build failed
> (from./node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ivy/index.js)
> ../.component.scss:17:100: ERROR: Unterminated string token
>
> *./src/polyfills.ts` - Error: Module build failed
> (from./node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ivy/index.js)
> ../.component.scss:17:100: ERROR: Unterminated string token

This angular version

```
    Angular CLI: 14.0.6
    Node: 16.16.0
    Package Manager: NPM 8.14.0
    OS: win32 x64
    
    Angular: 14.0.6
    
    Package                         Version
    ---------------------------------------------------------
    @angular-devkit/architect       0.1400.6
    @angular-devkit/build-angular   14.0.6
    @angular-devkit/core            14.0.6
    @angular-devkit/schematics      14.0.6
    `@angular/cdk                   14.0.5`
    @angular/material               14.0.5
    @nguniversal/express-engine     7.1.1
    @schematics/angular             14.0.6
    `rxjs                           6.6.7`
    typescript                      4.6.4
```

/.component.scss

```
input[type=text]:disabled {
  color: black;
}

.search-row {
  .form-group > label {
    font-size: 1.1em !important;
      color: black;
  }
}

.mat-table {
  th.mat-header-cell {
    font-size: 1.1em !important;
      color: black;
  }
}//<< here line 17.


#block {
  margin: 0% 10%;
}
...
```

Comment: What does line 17 from ../.component.scss look like?

(There are some strange string tokens in your posted information that make me uncomfortable, but are probably unrelated. `*./src/polyfills.ts[string token] Error: Module build failed`, for example)

Comment: I solved it, I think it's about my ```angular.json``` file.

Comment: Would you mind sharing the changes you did in the `angular.json` file?

Comment: @Thelopera can you share the solution

Comment: I new my `angular.json`file from  `ng new`

Answer (score 44):

For anyone landing there, temporarily set `optimization: false` in your angular.json file. The will allow to see the real error.

In my case it was an unsupported stylesheet import. But it can be any error thrown by Webpack sass-loader.

Comment: Amazing. I spent 4 hours yesterday fixing the same weird issue. Disabling the `optimization` temporarily gave me the exact issue. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thanks for the hint .... I think we hit some Angular compiler bug - hiding the root cause of the problem. After doing your trick I found that my SCSS has a bad import :/

Comment: it doesn't give me the exact issues. Though optimization is set to false, same errors are occured.

Comment: Thanks a lot!  When I disabled the optimization, the terminal shows the correct error files!!!!!

Comment: Please try this to solve the issue.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71916458/editor-component-scss17100-error-unterminated-string-token-angular-scss/74427603#74427603

Answer (score 13):

I added the "path/name" of the scss files in angular.json->projects->project name ->architect->build->options->styles as following then I could find the exact scss issues.

```
{
  ...
  "projects": {
    ...
    "my-project": {
      ...
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          ...
          "options": {            
            ...
            "styles": [
            ...
            "src/scss/style.scss",
            "src/app/components/playlistDetail/playlist-detail.component.scss",
            ...
            ]
          }
        },
```

Then I could see Sass error as following.

```
./src/app/components/items/viewitem/viewitem.component.ts - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ivy/index.js):
Error: Transform failed with 1 error:
E:/f2022_indy/front/src/app/components/fan/fan.component.scss:17:100: ERROR: Unterminated string token

./src/app/components/fan/fan.component.scss - Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js):
SassError: Expected whitespace.
   ╷
89 │         @media screen and(max-width: 767px) {
   │                          ^
   ╵
  src\app\components\fan\fan.component.scss 89:26  root stylesheet
```

Comment: This solution helped to find out the error in the scss file. Thank you so much for sharing.

Comment: This was the effective solution to diagnose the real issue in my case.  Line 17 of my .scss file in my error was whitespace between two scss rules, and deleting and re-adding the whitespace didn't help.  When I plugged my stylesheets into the styles property, it turned out I hadn't properly updated all my scss stylesheet imports after renaming a higher-level folder.

Answer (score 5):

Run the following command

```
npx browserslist --update-db
```

Comment: Latest version:     1.0.30001418
Installed version:  1.0.30001418
caniuse-lite is up to date
caniuse-lite has been successfully updated

No target browser changes

Comment: Or if using yarn: `yarn dlx browserslist --update-db`

Answer (score 1):

I upgraded angular project from 5.2 to 14, I saw this error and its not displayed from which file the error came from.

I tried  `optimization: false` in `angular.json` file but it did not work since upgrade converted `.angular-cli.json` to `angular.json` and json structure seems to be wrong.

**I created a new sample project with angular and moved `angular.json` file from there to upgraded project folder, then changed `optimization: false`**

This time errors shown are specific with line and file name. I resolved those errors in project css files and able to do `ng serve`

Answer (score 1):

One fix might be to temporarily set the `optimization` key to `false` in the `angular.json` file. This will help you to see if the real issue is then reported.

If that doesn't change anything, then have a look at your imports. We had an issue whereby one of the `paths` options within the `tsconfig.json` file had been used within a scss file:

```
@import '@shared/scss/core'
```

But this `@shared` is ignored for SCSS files by webpack unless you use the `TsconfigPathsWebpackPlugin` plugin.

The simple solution was to use change it to this instead, bypassing the need for `paths` in the `tsconfig` file at all for this SCSS file:

```
@import 'app/shared/scss/core'
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone that still has this issue, you can set `optimization: false` in your angular.json file and rebuild to see the real error with details and then put `optimization: true` back.

for me the error was that i had an $dark-color variable that is undefined.

Answer (score 0):

in angular 14 there was same error here:
incorrect:

```
.user {
      width: calc(100% / 3);
      min-width: 340px;
      float: left;
      @media screen and(max-width: 1100px) {
        width: calc(100% / 2);
      }
      @media screen and(max-width: 735px) {
        width: 100%;
      }
    }
```

correct:

```
.user {
      width: calc(100% / 3);
      min-width: 340px;
      float: left;
      @media screen and (max-width: 1100px) {
        width: calc(100% / 2);
      }
      @media screen and (max-width: 735px) {
        width: 100%;
      }
    }
```

yeah, white space after 'and' resolve problem :)