# Angular 14 - Getting SASS errors unterminated errors at line 17

Tags: css, angular, sass, node-sass

We recently migrated from Angular v9 to Angular v14.

The project runs fine when we do `ng serve` but when we are trying to build the application using `ng build` it won't build and gives the below errors:

> Error: Transform failed with 1 error:
> src/app/administration-module/account-settings/add-database-details/add-database-details.component.sass:17:100: ERROR: Unterminated string token

Our latest code attempt:

```
.execute-box
  width: 25%
  position: fixed
  right: 0
  top: 65px
  background: white
  border: 1px solid black
  overflow-y: scroll
  //bottom: 64px
  box-shadow: 0 24px 24px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.39)
  border: solid 1px #c8c8c8
  background-color: #ffffff

.custom-checkbox .custom-control-label::before
  width: 18.6px
  height: 18px
  border-radius: 2px
  border: solid 1px #707070
  background-color: #ffffff
```

Steps we've tried to solve the issue:

- Installed/uninstalled `node-sass`
- Re-wrote the parts of the code mentioned in the error with the proper syntax of sass (the latest code mentioned above)
- Re-installed Node modules
- Downgraded and upgraded the `node-sass` version

Comment: question is unclear. You should share some more information.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: looks similar to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71916458/editor-component-scss17100-error-unterminated-string-token-angular-scss

Comment: That's SCSS, it didn't work for me. We are using SASS

Comment: Either you add `add-database-details.component.sass` code or this question is getting closed.

Comment: I would have probably voted to reopen if the code/text was included as code-blocks rather than images.  But as mentioned above, we have *many* reasons for asking that you not post images in place of code/text.  Can you make that edit as requested? Thanks!

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds thanks in advance, this is the first time asking a question for me, mostly I gave answers so didn't know how to do it. please check and let me know

Comment: Thanks @SainathS - Please review my edits and let me know if it looks accurate.  Also, to be clear, you mentioned that you *"Re-written the error places with the proper syntax of sass"* - Is the code above the updated/rewritten code or the original code?  You should probably include both. Thanks!

Comment: yes @NotTheDr01ds The code above is the updated code.

Comment: tl;dr from the duplicate targets - set optimization to false in your angular.json file and re-build to see the real error. This error is misleading--it could be anything.

Comment: @TylerH ya did that but still the same thing, I'm afraid that now I have to change the stylesheet to scss/css in my project.

Comment: @SainathS I believe the point is that you should now see a different error that should be more helpful after making that change.  Did that happen?